# IIS - Localhost not working - Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: iis, windows-7-x64

Please help me and I have spent lot of time on this (uninstalled & installed IIS several times) & got frustrated.

I have installed IIS in windows 7 home premium but when I browse http://localhost nothing is coming. I mean initially it says "Diagnose Connection problem" then I created the folder wwwroot manually under c:\inetpub and reinstalled again then it copied the iis home page files to wwwroot folder. Now it displays blank page.

I don't have any clue on what to do... So, please help me to resolve this.

Also, I have tried everything (i.e. http://localhost:80, http://127.0.0.1 & etc...) but nothing works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you copy the iisstart and the welcome png file?

Comment: No. Actually the wwwroot folder was not created initially inside the inetpub but later I created that folder manually and reinstalled IIS again then those files were copied. But when I browse the default web site or http://localhost a blank page is displayed but no error.

Comment: I just followed this link and everything seems to be fine now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark...

Make sure there is a default website under the sites folder in the IIS console